# How do you update a checked out repository with a new repository URL in SVN?

Tags: svn

Due to some server changes and restructuring, I want to change to url for our repository from

http://unitas.sports-reference.com/svn/br_repos/br/trunk
http://foo.example.com/svn/repos

to

http://bar.example.com/svn/repos

I can handle the updating, of the repository itself, but how do I update a checked out copy of the repository without having to drop it and then check it back out.  svn switch?  It's the exact same repository, just in a new location.

thanks

Comment: Once I got the answers below I found a similar question.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6417092/svn-switch-what-does-relocate-do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [svn relocate](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.relocate.html), or [svn switch --relocate](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.relocate) if you are on an older svn client version that does not have the `svn relocate` command.

Answer (score 1):

If you access to svn command line :

```
sudo svn switch --relocate http://old.example.com/repo http://new.example.com/repo
```